# Keras - Logging loss that is made of multiple values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm using the following code to train a model. The loss is made of two different terms that are then summed up. I'd like to log each separated values for both train and validation. In particular I'd like to log the values `loss_mmd` and `loss_nll`. I'd like to keep the training procedure with the `model.fit()`.

```
encoder_input = Input(shape=(raw.shape[1], raw.shape[2],1))
...
encoder = Model(encoder_input,[mu,sigma,latent_space], name='encoder')
...
decoder_input = Input(shape=(z_dim,))
...
decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name='decoder')

train_z = encoder(encoder_input)[2]
train_xr = decoder(train_z)
autoencoder = Model(encoder_input, train_xr)


def custom_loss(train_z, train_xr, train_x):

  loss_mmd = compute_mmd(latent_space, train_z)       # scalar output
  loss_nll = K.mean(K.square(train_xr - train_x))       # scalar output

  return loss_nll, loss_mmd


#compile the model, prepare for training
loss = custom_loss(train_z, train_xr, encoder_input)
autoencoder.add_loss(sum(loss))
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam')


#Train the model
vae=autoencoder.fit(data_train,
                    epochs=epoch,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=(data_val, None))
```

Comment: https://keras.io/api/metrics/#as-simple-callables-stateless